# Including all libraries, audio, etc. of a Java program in one JAR file

Tags: java, netbeans, audio, jar, getresource

I am using Netbeans and I am trying to figure out how I can put all of my libraries, music, images, etc. in one JAR file for distribution.  I think I have the libraries figured out, but the audio, images, and other such files are giving me trouble.

In my current project I have an audio file that I want to embed in the JAR file too.  First I tried `one-jar` but after a couple of hours I gave up on it.  I put the audio file into the JAR file just fine, but I cannot access it from my program.  I know I need to use `getResourceAsStream` as suggested [here](http://capturevision.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/how-to-embed-resource-files-using-netbeans/) but I am unclear what I do after I get the input stream.  The only way I can see to make it work is to use use the `InputStream` and create a whole new file (seen below... and it works), **but creating a new file seems like a waste** (and I don't want people to see an audio file appear when my program is running).  **Is there no way to directly access the audio file while it is still contained in the `.JAR` file?**

```
File file = new File("myAudio.wav");
InputStream stream = mypackage.MyApp.class.getResourceAsStream("audio/myAudio.wav");
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

**EDIT:**

The internal structure of my JAR file Contains 1.) a library package ([Jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)), 2.) my package which is the direct parent of my class files and a folder called "audio" which contains `myAudio.wav`, and 3.) a `META-INF` folder which contains my `manifest.mf`.

**EDIT**

Audio stream is read something like this.  I have tried to use the `InputStream` directly but I have not had success.  I want to point out again that I already have it when I create a new audio file from the input stream of the audio file contained `JAR` file, but like I said before, it seems like a waste to create a big audio file every time a program is run when the file already exists in the `JAR`.  This file recreation is what I am trying to avoid.

```
AudioInputStream stream;
Clip music;
        try {
            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        }
        try {
            music = AudioSystem.getClip();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        }
        try {
            start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
public void start() throws Exception {
    music.open((AudioInputStream) stream);
    music.start();
    music.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}
```

Comment: Can you detail your jar organization ? (I mean, a `tree` on the unzipped jar)

Comment: @Riduidel I added some detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(stream);` work for you?

Comment: Yes it does.  You sir are the man... Don't know how I missed it :)